# Magento Model - View - Controller - how that works in short?

Tags: template, blocks, layout, controllers, mvc

can anyone describe me in short version how Magento works with MVC, models i somehow understand, but how view and controllers in magento are diffrerent than in onther mvc systems? magento says that  View has been separated into Blocks and Templates. But what in real life do they do? what then is phtml file which i can load into controller? and what for example is system.xml file, where i define fields that i am going to have? is that view - template? i am really confused, i hope someone can describe this short.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this series of Alan Storm's articles about Magento MVC: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers